# Setting the cursor to a vertical thin line in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to set the cursor in insert mode to be a thin vertical line and I am unable to. I have tried this in my .vimrc file:

```
set guicursor+=i:ver100-iCursor
```

It does not set the cursor to a vertical bar on insert mode.

What am I missing and how do I do this?

Comment: Are you using gVim or the command-line Vim?

Comment: Isn't it a default behavior in gvim?

Comment: I want to make it a thin vertical bar and not a block

Comment: I didn't know that it was the default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This did the trick:

`set guicursor=i:ver25-iCursor`

I had to reduce the `100` to `25`

Comment: I see, that makes sense. If the cursor was a `100` then naturally it would be 100% thick, making it a block cursor. Good job finding that. :)

Comment: What Operating System was this on?  Didn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Nathan In Ubuntu 20.04 you can change it in the Preference settings on the terminal (right click anywhere in a terminal and select Preferences) by selecting cursor shape=i-beam.

Comment: @adosar  Thx!  Will try when I get home.  Can't believe I didn't check my SO inbox for a whole week, weird

Answer (score 21):

**This code in my `/home/el/.vimrc` worked for my console:**

```
if $TERM_PROGRAM =~ "iTerm"
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7" " Vertical bar in insert mode
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7" " Block in normal mode
endif
```

**Which does this for me:**

[image]

**Source:**

https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2014-03-09-change-vim-cursor-in-iterm.html

Answer (score 15):

For gnome terminal version>3.15
Add this to your ~/.vimrc.

```
if has("autocmd")
  au VimEnter,InsertLeave * silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[2 q"' | redraw!
  au InsertEnter,InsertChange *
\ if v:insertmode == 'i' | 
\   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[6 q"' | redraw! |
\ elseif v:insertmode == 'r' |
\   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[4 q"' | redraw! |
\ endif
au VimLeave * silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[ q"' | redraw!
endif
```

You will get a block cursor in normal mode and a thin one in insert mode.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work on my Ubuntu 14.04. Cursor is still block-shape after adding these lines.   Any possible reson?

Comment: Really? So if we open a new terminal, the `~/.vimrc` will anyway be valid, right?  I did that. Really confused.  What did you do after modify `~/.vimrc`?  And could you please post a screenshot of your cursor after the configuration works?

Comment: this worked for me too, but the redraw is very annoying.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with Vim8, Ubuntu 20.04, and Gnome Terminal 3.36.

Answer (score 2):

I use `iTerm2` on mac and none of the above worked. Silly (`vim` and interface ain't right) but works. To switch between vertical bar or box. Profiles -> Open Profiles... -> Edit Profiles... -> Text

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works for me as all. All the other solutions didn't work for me (in both mac and iTerm).