# Thin cursor in console vim

Tags: vim

I would like to get a thin cursor in console vim - I tried the approaches described in [Setting the cursor to a vertical thin line in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137623/setting-the-cursor-to-a-vertical-thin-line-in-vim), but that didn't seem to work out, perhaps because they were more meant for gvim.

This is on Linux Mint 17.3 - `gnome-terminal` v3.6.2

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2):

This post has detailed steps for most terminals.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes

I use iTerm on OS X, so I have following in my `vimrc` file.

```
if exists('$TMUX')
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7\<Esc>\\"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7\<Esc>\\"
else
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
endif
```

Comment: @Cenoc, the code I posted is for `iTerm` only. Check the link for what to do for `gnome-terminal`, looks like you have to configure it differently depending on the version of `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that and realized what you meant a bit later. I tried using what they recommended for gnome-terminal, but I get `E355: Unknown option: t_SR` for the second option and the first one doesn't seem to change anything... hrmmm

Comment: I don't have access to a `gnome-terminal`, so can't help you here.